# Can the Xcode debugger inspect a pointed-to struct's member values?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, pointers, struct

I am using a pointer to an array of structs in Xcode. In debugging, when I inspect the pointer, all I can get is the value of the pointer variable itself - the address in memory it points to. Is there a way for the debugger to show me the dereferenced values of the struct's members, just like it is able to show the values of instance variables of a given object? Since an object is a pointer to an array of contiguous memory - not that different than a struct - it seems reasonable to expect this capability. Does anyone know how to do this? I know I could put in a bunch of NSLog statements, but I'd rather simply be able to see the member values at any given time while debugging. I appreciate any help you can give me. Thanks!